# how to switch between windows in linux with command

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

I was studying about "AutoKey" and I understood that it interprets the keys as a button and create scripts..

[image "AutoKey"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv6SM.png)

I'm using

```
"window.activate('Google Chrome')"
```

however it switches only to google chrome. How do you switch between two programs when you press a key?

Example:

"window.activate('Google Chrome')" - I'm on chrome

"window.activate('explorer.exe')" - I'm in the archive folder

I want them to toggle when I press a key

[bar fedora](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVJo7.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to toggle, then you have to find out where you are to start with. Start your script by getting the the window title...

NOTE: The following is untested code.

If it doesn't work and you can't easily figure out why, post on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/autokey/autokey) and we'll figure it out. The script below will fail as written because I don't think you can have empty except: clauses. The least you can do is add a `pass` statement to each of them so the error is ignored and doesn't throw an exception.

I assume that your window title strings are correct although explorer.exe gives me pause because I'm not sure that will run on Linux and AutoKey is a Linux X11 application. It does not work on Wayland or on Windows.

```
win = window.get_active_title()
if win == 'Google Chrome' :
    try:
        window.activate('explorer.exe')
    except:
        ## do something if that didn't work
elif win == 'explorer.exe'
    try:
        window.activate('Google Chrome')
    except:
        ## do something if that didn't work
else
    ## do something when neither is the active window
```

If one or both of those windows/apps aren't running when this script is launched, then something will fail. You can either try to launch them or do something else depending on your requirements.

I don't think the first API call can fail, but you can put that in a try: block too if necessary.

Also, when things look right, but still don't work, the first thing to try is to add long delays before/between all the API calls with something like `time.sleep(1)`. Once the script works, you can reduce or eliminate the delays one at a time.